# How to set a $scope variable to true via $routeParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to set and retrieve ids with `$routeParams`:

```
.when('/building/:buildingId', 

ng-href="#/building/{{building.objectId}}">
```

What I want to do now is to set a `$scope` variable to true based on `$routeParams`. So when I click the link the `$scope` variable is set to true in the target page.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.var = $routeParams.buildingId
```

OR, if you like to set the `$scope` var to `TRUE`

```
$scope.var = $routeParams.buildingId === undefined ? false : true
```

Comment: @alexchenco Have I understood your question correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what should I pass in `{{building.objectId}}`? I just want to pass something to the URL to make that scope variable true.

Comment: @alexchenco If you use the second approach I suggested, you can pass anything you like e.g. `#/building/1` or `#/building/asdf` will set the `$scope` field `var` to `true`. If you open the URL `#/building` the `$scope` field `var` will be `false`. You can check it